# How to boot into expert install?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

How can I boot my Ubuntu Server 18 LTS into expert install? The advanced options seem to be missing and F6 + "Expert mode" doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Are you talking about "Something else' option during install?

Comment: @Vijay When exactly should this appear?